# Integrate TinyMCE to django

Tags: django, django-forms, tinymce-4, django-tinymce

Unlike most articles , i am not trying to integrate the tinyMCE into the admin page.

I'm building a site with multiple blog's and i want to integrate tinyMCE into a textarea where the user is supposed to enter his article. The above mentioned textarea is not in the admin console.

I read the [docs](http://django-tinymce.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html) and followed the steps line by line. The only change that i made was instead of MEDIA_ROOT i used STATIC_ROOT.

My `Setting.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'tinymce',
    'pages',
    'blog',
    'django_summernote',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = {
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',

}

STATIC_ROOT = 'F:/Projects/trebuchet/site/blog_test/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

############ TINY MCE ################

TINYMCE_JS_URL = os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, "static/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js")

TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, "static/tiny_mce")

TINYMCE_JS_URL = os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT,'static/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js')
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    "relative_urls": "false",
    "theme": "advanced",
    "theme_advanced_buttons1":     "formatselect,bold,italic,underline,link,unlink,bullist,undo,code,image",
    "theme_advanced_buttons2": "",
    "theme_advanced_buttons3": "",
    "plugins": "paste",
    "height": "550px",
    "width": "750px",
}

TINYMCE_SPELLCHECKER = True
TINYMCE_COMPRESSOR = True
```

`BlogForm.py`

```
class addBlog(forms.ModelForm):
    body = forms.CharField(widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30}))
    class Meta:
        model = ArticleModel
        fields = ['title', 'body',  'category']
        widgets = {'body': TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30})}

    class Media:
                js = ( 'static/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js', 'static/tiny_mce/blog_textareas.js')
```

`models.py`

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name



class ArticleModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    tags = JSONField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Now i tried a lot of solutions, with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, why don't you try adding ckeditor(another rich text editor) to your adminsite by using javascript version of ckeditor, for example:

Download ckeditor from http://ckeditor.com/download and extract the zip file, put the unzipped folder in static root. add ckeditor static files to your admin's template like:

In admin>base.html(template):

```
<script src="{{STATIC_URL}}ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

From your class ArticleModel, I am assuming you want to add ckeditor to `body`, and in admin site, it will create a TextField with id `id_body`, so all you need to do is this(in admin>base.html):

```
<script>
  CKEDITOR.replace( '#id_body' );
</script>
```

Ps: I am ignoring forms here.